# yii: validate multiple models

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a Competition model, that has many Entry models.

[**edit**] Schema looks (roughly) like this:

Competition:

> id INT(11)
>
> name VARCHAR(50)
>
> date DATETIME

Entry:

> id INT(11)
>
> competition_id INT(11)
>
> user_id INT(11)
>
> answer VARCHAR(50)
>
> isWinner INT(1)

In my `pickWinner` view, I have a form that loops through all related entries - offering the `isWinner` field to allow the user to pick an entry as the winner. Saving the related model etc is pretty standard and that all works fine.

I'm trying to validate the form so that at least one of the Entry models has `isWinner` set to true (the user has to pick at least one winner).

I obviously can't apply the validation rule to the Entry model - as each model only knows about itself and not the values of the other models.

Only one Entry model should be set as the winner - how do I add a validation rule to Competition, so that it can detect that one of its child Entry models has `isWinner` set to true?

Comment: so you are saying that the entries have already been created? and user will only be selecting an entry as the winner in this view?

Comment: Exactly so, yes. Thanks for putting it better than I did!

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103607/yii-multiple-records-in-one-form-submission/16411773#16411773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>One way to achieve this would be to add a relation to the Competition model to detect if it has a winner, something like;</strike>

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'winners' => array(self::STAT, 'Entry', 'competition_id', 'condition'=>'`t`.`isWinner` = true'),
        ...
    );
}
```

Then the following should return the number of winners for the given competition:

```
$competition = Competition::model()->findByPk($id);
$winners = $competition->winners;
```

Not tested, so you may need to alter a little.

**EDIT**

Ok, to get this info before you save you could do something like the following: if for example in your `pickWinner` view you have a field for each model and it's submitting back as an array, for example like `$_POST[Entry][$model->id]['isWinner']` for each model, can you not simply cycle through those making sure one is set to true? e.g:

```
$winners = 0;
foreach(array_keys($_POST[Entry]) as $key)
{
    if($_POST[Entry][$key]['isWinner']=='true')
        $winners++;
}

if($winners==0)
{
    echo "You selected no winners.";
} else if($winners>1) {
    echo "You selected too many winners.";
} else if($winners==1) {
    echo "Woot, 1 winner!";
}
```

Again, this depends on how your `pickWinner` form is laid out.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I'd need to check that a winner was chosen before saving the changes to the models, so it needs to be a validation rule. Also, the isWinner flag is in the Entry, not the Competition. Schema added above to explain a bit more.

Comment: Edited answer, let me know if your pickWinner view is laid out differently

Comment: Thanks - yes, the view is laid out to submit the entries as an array. I've ended up doing something similar to that in the controller's performAjaxValidation method, but it feels like a kludge and not really the "Yii way", plus it means I can't validate client-side. Ideally i'm looking for a more Yii-like method that allows "proper" Yii validation to work.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'Yii' way to validate across multiple relations unfortunately. You could maybe validate clientside with javascript, ensuring only one (I assume dropdown or radio button) `isWinner` element is set to true?

Comment: Yeah, that's another possibility. I don't totally trust client-only validation though - it's too easy for the user to mess with it. I guess I'll have to stick with a kludge.

Comment: oh definitely, you have to validate server side too :) just client side as an additional check usually results in a better experience for the end user.