# YII loading datepicker in partial view breaks table layout

Tags: yii

I have a form, part of which has tabular input for milestones with an ajax function to add a new row.

Here's the function the ajax calls:

```
public function actionNewMilestoneRow($index)
{
  $milestoneModel = new TgifMilestone;
  $this->renderPartial('_milestone', array(
    'milestoneModel' => $milestoneModel,
    'i' => $index,
  ),false,true);
}
```

Here's the table portion of the view with the JS to add an extra row:

```
  <table class="timeline">
  <tbody class="milestones">
  <tr><th>Milestone</th><th>Expected<br />Completion Date</th></th></tr>
  <?php foreach ($milestoneModels as $i=>$milestoneModel): ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $form->textField($milestoneModel,"[$i]milestone",array('size'=>75,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($milestoneModel,"[$i]milestone]"); ?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?php
  $date_value=empty($milestoneModel->expected_completion_date)?date('l, M j, Y'):$milestoneModel->expected_completion_date;
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
      'model'=>$milestoneModel, //Model object
      'language'=>'',
      'attribute'=>"[$i]expected_completion_date", //attribute name
      'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat' => 'DD, M d, yy',// equivalent to PHP date 'l, M j, Y'
        'defaultDate'=>$date_value,//see above
      ), // jquery plugin options
  ));
  ?>
<?php echo $form->error($milestoneModel,"[$i]expected_completion_date"); ?>
</td>
</tr>    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php echo CHtml::button('Add Another Milestone', array('class' => 'milestone-add')) ?>    
<script>
$(".milestone-add").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(html){
      $(".milestones").append(html);
    },
    type: 'get',
    url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('newMilestoneRow');?>',
    data: {
      index: $(".milestones tr").size() - 1
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html'
  });
});    
</script>
```

Everything works fine for an added row if I render partial without the return and processoutput:

```
  $this->renderPartial('_milestone', array(
    'milestoneModel' => $milestoneModel,
    'i' => $index,
  ));
```

except that the datepicker does not show, but the table renders correctly.

When I add return and process output  I get the datepicker but it breaks the table:

```
  $this->renderPartial('_milestone', array(
    'milestoneModel' => $milestoneModel,
    'i' => $index,
  ),false,true);
```

The table row and table cell tags disappear:

```
<tr><!-- this is the row befoe the added row -->
<td><input id="TgifMilestone_4_milestone" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[4][milestone]" maxlength="250" size="75"></td>
<td><input id="TgifMilestone_4_expected_completion_date" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[4][expected_completion_date]"></td>
</tr>
<link href="/requests/assets/f73aa0bb/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="TgifMilestone_5_milestone" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[5][milestone]" maxlength="250" size="75">
<input id="TgifMilestone_5_expected_completion_date" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[5][expected_completion_date]">
</tbody>
</table>
```

without the return and process output it renders like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input id="TgifMilestone_5_milestone" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[5][milestone]" maxlength="250" size="75"></td>
<td><input id="TgifMilestone_5_expected_completion_date" type="text" name="TgifMilestone[5][expected_completion_date]"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas how to fix it so I get both the table row and the datepicker for the added row?

Adding _milestone.php partial view at bool.dev's request;

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($milestoneModel,"[$i]milestone",array('size'=>75,'maxlength'=>250)); ?></td>
<td>
<?php
$date_value=empty($milestoneModel->expected_completion_date)?date('l, M j, Y'):substr($milestoneModel->expected_completion_date,0,10);//default date must be a date not a datetime
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
      'model'=>$milestoneModel, //Model object
      'language'=>'',
      'attribute'=>"[$i]expected_completion_date", //attribute name
      'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat' => 'DD, M d, yy',// equivalent to PHP date 'l, M j, Y'
        'defaultDate'=>$date_value,//see above, date not datetime..

      ), // jquery plugin options

));
?> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show your _\_milestone.php_ partial view?

Comment: added as requested. I use the default date for a datetimepicker also hence the cruft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `processOutput` is loading *jquery.js*, *jquery-ui.min.js*, and *jquery-ui.css* again, which results in the incorrect elements. Even though `CJuiDatePicker` needs these files, loading them once (during first rendering) is enough, and in subsequent ajax calls, we can just avoid loading them again.

To do that you can simply modify the *_milestone.php* partial view file:

```
<?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js']=false;
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.css']=false;
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.min.js']=false;
?>
<!-- rest of your _milestone.php -->
```

---

What is happening is that when `processOutput` encounters the registerScript calls for the above 3 files, it'll just be ignored, but the rest of the scripts (like activation) required for `CJuiDatePicker` will be included in the script.

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks. You nailed it and have added to the kb for YII tabular input with dynamic rows. It's a shame there's no good solution for validation of the added rows. That would really make my day. Maybe I should run a bounty for that.

Comment: glad to help! for validation, see if you can get some idea from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109406/720508).

Comment: changed the scriptMap slightly

Comment: that's a subtle difference. As I see it: adding versus overriding the whole map.

Comment: thanks for the validation link. I found for ajax validation with tabular input and multiple models that this post was very helpful as a launch point: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21125-ajax-validation-for-tabular-or-dynamic-input/