# (UPD) Not restricted tabular input on yii

Tags: php, mysql, validation, input, yii

Please excuse me, if this question already was on StackExchange, but I didn't found it not on Stack, not in Google.

Problem, from one view, is simple: I need to implement tabular input on Yii framework. There is no problem, if I wan't to add multiple rows into database table. For example:

WorkController::actionBatchCreate(). [Source: Yii - multiple records in one form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103607/yii-multiple-records-in-one-form-submission).

```
    public function actionBatchCreate()
{
    $models=array();
    // since you know how many models
    $i=0;
    while($i < 5)
    {
        $models[]=Work::model();
        $i++;
        // you can also allocate memory for the model with `new Modelname` instead
        // of assigning the static model
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Work']))
    {
        $valid=true;
        foreach ($_POST['Work'] as $j=>$model)
        {
            if (isset($_POST['Work'][$j]))
            {
                $models[$j]=new Work; // if you had static model only
                $models[$j]->attributes=$model;
                $valid=$models[$j]->validate() && $valid;
            }
        }
        if ($valid)
        {
            $i=0;
            while(isset($models[$i]))
            {
                $models[$i++]->save(false);// models have already been validated
            }
            // anything else that you want to do, for example a redirect to admin page
            $this->redirect(array('work/admin'));
        }
    }

    $this->render('batchcreate',array('models'=>$models));
}
```

View: batchcreate.php. [Source: Collecting Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table)

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Measure</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Work</th>
        <th>Mat</th>
        <th>Mech</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($models as $m=>$model): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]work_name"); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]measure"); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]count"); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]work",array('size'=>8)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]material",array('size'=>8)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$m]mechanisms",array('size'=>8)); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

As seen in `actionBatchCreate()` - it will create 5 models Work (5 rows in form). It will work perfect, if I need to add only 5 records into the database, not less or more. But if I want to add less - problems begins. Because of `$valid` variable, it won't save empty row, so they will highlighted, if they're empty. If I remove validation - it will add empty records into the database.
On my opinion, there is something must be done with second cycle: `while(isset($models[$i]))`, another condition must be added. For example: check if some field is not empty in form, if true - ignore it, but I don't know how to get values from model, because I'm new in Yii. 
Halp, pl0x.

**UPD**:

I have tried to implement this thing. I changed `$valid` variable into `array()`, so its members would correspond to each model:

```
    public function actionBatchCreate()
{
    $models=array();
    $valid=array();
    // since you know how many models
    $i=0;
    while($i < 5)
    {
        $models[]=Work::model();
        $valid[$i]=0; // all false
        $i++;
        // you can also allocate memory for the model with `new Modelname` instead
        // of assigning the static model
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Work']))
    {

        foreach ($_POST['Work'] as $j=>$model)
        {
            if (isset($_POST['Work'][$j]))
            {
                $models[$j]=new Work; // if you had static model only
                $models[$j]->attributes=$model;
                if($models[$j]->validate()===true)
                {
                    $valid[$j]=1; // true
                }
            }
        }
        $i=0;
        while(isset($models[$i]))
        {
           if($valid[$i]===1) // if valid[i] true, then save
           {
               $models[$i]->save();// models have already been validated
           }
           $i++;
        }
        // anything else that you want to do, for example a redirect to admin page
        $this->redirect(array('work/admin'));
    }

    $this->render('batchcreate',array('models'=>$models));
}
```

In result it doesn't save anything, just jumps to the line `$this->redirect(array('work/admin'));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found by using [multimodelform](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multimodelform) extension.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution I can propose next simple approach for form data handling:

```
if (isset($_POST['Work']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['Work'] as $j => $model)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['Work'][$j]))
        {
            $models[$j] = new Work();
            $models[$j]->attributes = $model;
            $models[$j]->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that I removed section with `if ($valid) {}` and all other related stuff. This is because `$model->save()` actually performs data validation and in your case you don't need separated validation and saving processes.

Comment: Still, even without `$valid`, it will highlight fields, that are not filled with data. There must be some way to check, if one of the model property is empty, then ignore this model.